# How to create a dropbox form that sends out e-mail

Tags: javascript, html, dropbox, contact-form

A friend of mine is [hosting his website via Dropbox](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-host-a-dropbox-website/).

In the past, to create contact forms, I've used PHP. However, from what I could see, Dropbox limits you to Javascript and HTML since there's no server-side scripting.

Seems like the only way to create a contact form that sends out an e-mail is to link to an externally hosted site that is capable of doing server-side scripting.

I want to be sure before suggesting that he purchases some hosting. Does anyone have any other solution they've used?

Comment: You could use a [Google Drive form](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/87809?hl=en), or [wufoo](http://www.wufoo.com/). Not ideal, but options.

Comment: I second the Wufoo suggestion